# ajax post getting value in CLASSIC asp of html

Tags: ajax, jquery, post, asp-classic

I am trying to get the value i am sending from one page to another using jquery ajax json.

This is my code:

```
function checkTheVin()
{   
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "checkVin.asp",
            data: 'theVIN=' + $("#vwVin").val(),
            cache: false,
            dataType: "html",
            beforeSend: function() {$.blockUI({ message: '<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />' });},
            complete: function(){$.unblockUI();},
            success: function(responseText){
                if (responseText.indexOf("GOOD") > -1)
                {
                    $("#theContent").html(responseText.replace("GOOD",""));
                }else{
                    //alert(data);
                }                   
            },
            error: function(responseText){alert('err: ' + responseText);},
        });
 }
```

However i never get a resonse back. It's null.

This is how i am getting it using CLASSIC asp:

```
dim vwVin

vwVin = request.QueryString("theVIN")
```

What am i doing incorrect?

David

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `GET` method in your ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "checkVin.asp",
    data: 'theVIN=' + $("#vwVin").val(),
    cache: false,
    dataType: "html",
    beforeSend: function() {$.blockUI({ message: '<img src="img/ajax-loader.gif" />' });},
    complete: function(){$.unblockUI();},
    success: function(responseText){
        if (responseText.indexOf("GOOD") > -1)
        {
            $("#theContent").html(responseText.replace("GOOD",""));
        }else{
            //alert(data);
        }                   
    },
    error: function(responseText){alert('err: ' + responseText);},
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have three options

**1.** Use the Request Object with out specifying the collection

```
dim vwVin   
vwVin = request("theVIN")
```

The web server will then search request collections for you, first the querystring and then the form.

**2.** Specify the Request.Form collection if you are using Ajax Post

```
$.ajax({ type: "POST", ...

dim vwVin  
vwVin = Request.Form("theVIN")
```

**3.** Specify the Request.QueryString collection if you are using Ajax GET

```
$.ajax({ type: "GET", ...

dim vwVin  
vwVin = Request.QueryString ("theVIN")
```